# How to serialize restsharp request object to json string

Tags: restsharp

Using restsharp to call a restful API, this works fine, however, how do I serialize the request object into a JSON string, so I can log what's being sent?

```
            var client = new RestClient("http://..."); 

            var request = new RestRequest("xxx/url", Method.POST);

            request.AddParameter("test", "string");
            request.AddParameter("test2",  "string2"); 

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` and create `JObject` from an anonymous object:

`string requestBodyAsJson = JObject.FromObject(new { test = string}).ToString();`